# fadeToggle() fails on chrome/safari due to display block on <a> tag

Tags: jquery

http://jsfiddle.net/GGsEt/3/

#### Works on firefox

HTML

```
<ul>
    <li class="lib_undefined">
       <span class="hidden_toggle">
           <a href="/">Test</a>
       </span>
    </li>
</ul>
​
```

CSS

```
.hidden_toggle{
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 20px;
    font-weight: 600;
    color: #999;
    line-height: 80px;
    display: none;
}
    .hidden_toggle a{
        color: #999;
        border: none;
        display: block;
        width: 100%;    
        height: 90px;
    }

.lib_undefined{
    min-height: 90px;
    border: 1px solid #000;
}
```

jQuery

```
$('.lib_undefined').hover(function(){
     $(this).children('.hidden_toggle').fadeToggle();
});​
```

Any known fixes? The `a` tag needs to fill the entire li, which is why display is set to block.

Comment: You're storing a block element (the 'a' tag) inside of an inline element (hidden_toggle). This can cause problems sometimes. Making hidden_toggle into a block element (i.e. a div) makes your js code work fine. One thing to note is that the callback is firing on both in and out, but the fadeToggle is failing on the inline span. This may be a jQuery bug.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When `fadeToggle()` works it added `display: inline` `CSS` to fade element. You may use some block element such as `div`/ `p` to wrap your `a`.

Just use

`display: inline-block` to `.hidden_toggle a` and hope your problem will solve.

ie.

```
.hidden_toggle a {
    color: #999;
    border: none;
    display: inline-block; // change here
    width: 100%;    
    height: 90px;
}
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/GGsEt/7/)**

#### Note

Though `display: inline-block` will fails for older IE versions.

Comment: Isn't the mouseleave optional?

Comment: Sorry, I had an edit... show/hide is not what I'm going for. I need the fade effect.

Comment: If a single arg is passed to `hover`, it's used as both in and out. [It's in the docs](http://api.jquery.com/hover/)

Comment: @x1a4 I know, but this passing two handler will works just fine

Comment: This doesn't change the behavior of the original code at all. It still doesn't fade. It still doesn't disappear on mouse leave. (In Chrome)

Comment: Your edit now works. Though note, of course, that `inline-block` doesn't work in older IE versions.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in how fadeToggle() function is implemented. If applied to a span-element, it will use display:inline on the element style as the end result of toggling in. Which is not what you want.

Change <span/> to <div/> in your html code for it to work everywhere:
http://jsfiddle.net/GGsEt/3/

If a span is a must for some semantic reasons, I see no other way than to use animate().

Comment: Interesting, I did not know it acted differently on span and div. Thanks for that info.